# GraphQL: Can Queries & Mutations be split into separate classes?

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python

In my Graphene-Django project, I have this structure:

Project level:

```
schema.py
```

App level:

```
schema.py
queries.py
mutations.py
```

This works well but the queries file has grown quite large.  Is there a way to split *class Query* into multiple classes and/or multiple files?

Robert

Answer (score 8):

From the perspective of the project schema file, you can use inheritance in your Query class to pull in each of your separate Query classes.  You can use the same technique to split your Mutation.  For example:

```
from django.conf import settings

import graphene
from graphene_django.debug import DjangoDebug

from app1.schema import App1Query, App1Mutation
from app2.schema import App2Query, App2Mutation

class Query(App1Query, App2Query, graphene.ObjectType):
     if settings.DEBUG:
         # Debug output - see
         # http://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/debug/
        debug = graphene.Field(DjangoDebug, name='__debug')

class Mutation(App1Mutation, App2Mutation, graphene.ObjectType):
    pass

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutation)
```

(Note that I'm also dynamically adding the debug class if `DEBUG` is True -- this has nothing to do with your question, but it's handy.)

You should able to use the same inheritance technique to further split your query if you need to, for example breaking apart `App1Query`.